# WebView crashing after some time

Tags: android, webview

In my Android game I am loading websites in WebView by calling `webViewRowA.loadUrl(www.website.com)` and after some time (random) the device crashes with the following traceback.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.webkit.BrowserFrame.getRequestInterceptor(BrowserFrame.java:1108)
at android.webkit.FrameLoader.handleRequestIntercept(FrameLoader.java:426)
at android.webkit.FrameLoader.handleHTTPLoad(FrameLoader.java:226)
at android.webkit.WebViewWorker.handleMessage(WebViewWorker.java:124)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you mentioned uses-permission entry in AndroidManifest.xml file?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

This is essential if your application wants to access the internet connection.

Comment: Ensure that you are following the instructions at: http://goo.gl/OMlL but still you are not able to load the website properly, try loading a different URL. 

Open the URL in the Android browser and ensure your URL is accessible in the default browser.

Answer (score 0):

No answer from me, but I'll second the fact that I have been seeing this the last few days as well (also, happens randomly). However, I am only seeing this happen on 2.2 devices. Perhaps a bug in Froyo? Need to do some more digging.

Star the issue. Looks like a bug in Froyo: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11533